# How to change the <font size> of SC Editor?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been using SC Editor, but for font size it uses `<font size="number"></font>`. Is there anyway to change it to `<span class="font+number"></span>`?

I've been looking in the plugin JS, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't see why this was tagged with "Zend Framework"; removed it.

Comment: 'Cause i'm using it with Zend Framework, but ok :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the xhtml plugin, even if you are using xhtml version of sceditor

```
$("textarea").sceditor({
    plugins: "xhtml"
});
```